# Self-hosting apk expansion files

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm working on an Android digital library app and would like to provide a collections of sample resources in various languages - one collection in each language - ideally as apk expansion files. I understand that I can only have a maximum of two APK expansion files using Google Play Store.

This is a two-part question:

1. Is there a way to host the .obb files on my server?
2. If so, is there a way to select a particular .obb file to use? (in the app UI, offer the user a choice of languages in which to receive sample content.)

Comment: Expansion files are downloaded as part of the install process before your application even runs. Are you sure apk expansion files are the right fit for what you need?

Comment: It's entirely possible that expansion files are not the answer.

I'm just curious to know if expansion files can be used apart from the Google Play Store (self-hosted app that checks a URL for an expansion file), and whether I could choose from multiple available expansion files.

Comment: I'm able to download obb file from self host however when trying to mount this file, I got error 20 (e.g. Internal Error). I'm not sure what is this and how to fix. I will update you when I find solution.